# How can I add data to apk?

Tags: backup, apk

What I know is:

- I can get `.apk` of installed application from `/data/app`
- I can get data of installed application from `/data/data`

What I want is:

Add/pack this application-data into `.apk` so-that when I install application from `.apk`, application should be installed with data.

Is it possible? Then How can I...?

Note: I use rooted device with android 4.2.2

Comment: Any problem in using `adb backup`? It creates a `.ab` file containing both the apk and data files. All you've to is execute `adb restore` to restore both.

Comment: That said: Please visit our [backup tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/backup/info) for details :)

Comment: The same way you add music to `.jpg`

Comment: @SarpSTA: What does that mean? What are you implying? Please be precise.